# error loading in background image using inline style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

One of my sections in my bootstrap template contains 2 divs side by side both of equal col width. On the left side I need a background picture to fill the div and on the right side I have some contact information. Everything displays correctly except the picture does not load. The image is currently in the same folder as the index.html so I am not sure why it will not load.

My html section:

```
 <section class="ftco-about img ftco-section ftco-no-pt ftco-no-pb" id="about-section">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row d-flex no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 d-flex">
                    <div class="img-about img d-flex align-items-stretch">
                      <div class="overlay"></div>
                      <div class="img d-flex align-self-stretch align-items-center" style="background-image:url(def.jpeg);">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 pl-md-5 py-5">
                    <div class="row justify-content-start pb-3">
                      <div class="col-md-12 heading-section ftco-animate">
                        <h1 class="big">About</h1>
                        <h2 class="mb-4">About Me</h2>
                        <p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>
                        <ul class="about-info mt-4 px-md-0 px-2">
                          <li class="d-flex"><span>Name:</span> <span>Ronaldo Fredrickson</span></li>
                          <li class="d-flex"><span>Date of birth:</span> <span>November 28, 1989</span></li>
                          <li class="d-flex"><span>Address:</span> <span>San Francisco CA 97987 USA</span></li>
                          <li class="d-flex"><span>Zip code:</span> <span>1000</span></li>
                          <li class="d-flex"><span>Email:</span> <span>ronaldo@gmail.com</span></li>
                          <li class="d-flex"><span>Phone: </span> <span>+1-2234-5678-9-0</span></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="counter-wrap ftco-animate d-flex mt-md-3">
                      <div class="text">
                        <p class="mb-4">
                          <span class="number" data-number="120">0</span>
                          <span>Project complete</span>
                        </p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-3">Download CV</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
```

Image should be appearing in this div

[image]

as you can see the image is where it should be:

[image]

Comment: What size is the image? There's a big chance the image loads correctly but it's not sized well (you're only seeing a corner). Use `style="background: url('/def.jpeg') 0 /cover"`. Which is the shorthand for `background-image: url('/def.jpeg'); background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use img

```
<img class="img d-flex align-self-stretch align-items-center" src="def.jpeg" alt="about">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `width` and `height` to the image.

```
<div class="img d-flex align-self-stretch align-items-center" style="background-image:url(def.jpeg); width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the above and image still does not show up

Comment: Another option is to use a `img` tag, that is sourced inside HTML itself.